# Is it safe to use non-ascii characters on Android app?

Tags: android, non-ascii-characters

I recently noticed that I save non-ascii characters to file and read those characters from files. Could this cause crash on some phones?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you write and read them using the same character encoding, they will appear nicely. Otherwise, they could look strange, but should not cause the app to crash.

Answer (score 0):

you can use unicode in your app